# web2py changes file extension of the uploaded file to txt

Tags: upload, web2py, fine-uploader

I am using fine-uploader.js and fine-uploader.css for uploading my files using web2py framework.

The callback in the controller is

```
def upload_callback():
    if 'qqfile' in request.vars:
        filename = request.vars.qqfile
        newfilename = db.doc.filename.store(request.body, filename)
        db.doc.insert(filename=newfilename,uploaded_by=auth.user.id)
    return response.json({'success': 'true'})
```

The Model

```
uploadfolder = os.path.join(request.folder, 'uploads')
db.define_table('doc',
    Field('name', requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('filename', 'upload',autodelete=True,uploadfolder=uploadfolder),
    Field('uploaded_by', db.auth_user)
    )
```

When I upload file `'test01.xls'`, web2py stores it in file `"doc.filename.bfbf907529358f82.7830302729.txt"`

I do not understand why the extension `xls` is being changed to txt. I have also tried uploading a `jpg` file. Web2py changes the extension of the uploaded file to txt. Can somebody help me.

Comment: web2py defaults to a "txt" extension when the filename has no extension. Can you confirm the value of `request.vars.qqfile`? Perhaps the filename is not coming through as expected.

Comment: The value of request.vars.qqfile is a fieldstorage object      FieldStorage('qqfile', 'test01.xls', b'\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1\x1a\xe1\x00\x00\x00\x00\........)  I must mention that I am using Python3.8 (in case that is what is causing it)

Answer (score 0):

As `request.vars.qqfile` is not the filename but a `cgi.FieldStorage` object, you cannot use it as the filename but must instead extract the filename from it:

```
    filename = request.vars.qqfile.filename
```

Alternatively, you can simply pass the `FieldStorage` object directly to the `.insert` method, and web2py will automatically handle extracting the filename and saving the file:

```
def upload_callback():
    if 'qqfile' in request.vars:
        db.doc.insert(filename=request.vars.qqfile, uploaded_by=auth.user.id)
    return response.json({'success': 'true'})
```